# what is the _lr_id_ localstorage item and where does it come from?

Tags: local-storage, user-tracking

It appears that localstorage contains an item called `_lr_id_` by default. It shows up on all browsers and recreates itself when localstorage is cleared. I tested this on an OSX laptop and a Linux laptop in 4 different browsers, so it's definitely not a plugin. It's not just on my site, there are other websites that have it too, like [reactivepad.com](https://reactivepad.com/). It contains a JSON object with a guid labeled userID like this:

```
{"userID":"a11f6077-86b4-47c5-ae8d-58859682b033"}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In case you're still wondering, this is created by [LogRocket](https://logrocket.com/)